# Generate CSR for x.509 authorization in external api

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, x509

I have to create web API (in asp .net core) that will integrate with external API (via REST requests).

External API provider asked me to generate CSR with the specified common name (because of external API use x.509 auth).

I have to test this in localhost and deploy it to the development server (later to production).

I just don't know how to do it. 
Where should i start? What tools or libs should I use?

I don't have any code yet, and my contact with the external provider is a bit limited.

Comment: I believe, you should start from `CertificateRequest` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=netcore-2.0

Answer (score 1):

For Certificate base authentication, client basically needs to create as csr(certificate request) which the external provider will sign and send back a
signed certificate. You can use openssl to generate CSR.So download openssl tool.

Step1

```
openssl genrsa -out client-cert.key 1024
```

this will generate a private key 1024 bits

Step 2:

```
openssl req -new -key client-cert.key -out client-cert.csr
```

this will generate a csr
During this process you will be asked to fill common name, company name and other details on openssl command prompt.

You should send the generated csr file to external provider. Thanks